# Sqlite select column and remove duplicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have sqlite database with table of songs, now I want to get artist list from this table for example, and I want to remove duplicate match, so if I have a artist 2 or 3 time for example so I will get it only once, any way to do it?

I am using no in:

```
SELECT artist FROM Songs ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [`distinct`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#distinct) keyword you can use:

```
select distinct artist from songs order by artist;
```

Alternatively, if you want a bit more than the artist name (say, the number of entries per artist), you could use a [`group by`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) clause:

```
select artist, count(*) as entries from songs group by artist order by artist;
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT DISTINCT artist FROM Songs ORDER BY name

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM Songs WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table GROUP BY id);
```

Comment: MTA wants to select data, not delete it.

Comment: Ohhh... sorry i misunderstood his question then.